# HTML Unit - read from a normal string?

Tags: java, html-table, htmlunit

I want to use HTML Unit for JAVA.
In all examples there will be read the HTML Code from a specific website.

But I want to read the HTML source from another String.

Like this:

```
String myString = "<html> myString and Content </html>";
HtmlPage page  = myString; // doesn´t work, how can I do something like this?
```

I see only examples like this:

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net");
```

Can I also read only a Table?
Like this:

```
String myTable = "<table><td></td></table>";
HtmlTable table = myTable; // doesn´t work, how can I do something like this?
```

My question is now, how can I convert this correct?
Can anybody help me, please.

Answer (score 2):

HtmlUnit isn't really designed for this use case, so it will always be a bit of a hassle to make it work. If you're not tied to HtmlUnit specifically, you might be better off using something like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/), which has better built-in support for parsing HTML from strings.

That said, if you are tied to HtmlUnit, it's possible to make this work. For inspiration, you could look at how HtmlUnit sets up HtmlPage objects [in its own test suite](http://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/htmlunit/src/test/java/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/SimpleWebTestCase.java#l164).

As you can see there, although there's no way to construct an HtmlPage directly from a String, you can make a MockWebConnection that'll give a canned response without involving the network. So your code could look something like this:

```
String html = "<html>Your html here</html>";
WebClient client = new WebClient();
MockWebConnection connection = new MockWebConnection();
connection.setDefaultResponse(html);
client.setWebConnection(connection);
HtmlPage page = client.getPage(someUrl);
```

(Apologies for any errors in the above -- I'm no longer on a Java project, so I don't have a convenient way to test this right now. That said, I did spend some time on a large Java project that used roughly this technique for a lot of tests. It worked reasonably well, but it tended to be a bit fragile when we upgraded HtmlUnit. Overall, we were happier when we moved to Jsoup.)

Comment: What is HtmlPage page = client.getPage(someUrl); -> someUrl in this case?

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think you can give it literally any URL and it will still give you the page you set up. So I guess you could use "http://example.com".

Comment: DId this work for you? If not I have another solution

Comment: @Arya: I would like to see your solution. It is OK to post an answer to your own question. Others like me might find it useful.

Comment: @Arya I'm also curious to see your solution!

Comment: @MossCollum I posted my solution

Comment: @MrSmith42 just posted my solution.

Comment: Link to 'its own test suite' was very helpful. [http://sourceforge.net/p/htmlunit/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/htmlunit]

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way of doing it, similar to Collum's but a little different.

```
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    URL url = new URL("http://example.com");
    WebRequest requestSettings = new WebRequest(url, HttpMethod.GET);

    StringWebResponse response = new StringWebResponse("<html> myString and Content </html>", url);

    HtmlPage page = HTMLParser.parseHtml(response, webClient.getCurrentWindow());
```

As for getting the table, it is possible. You can load it with the method above and extract it with the code below.

```
HtmlTable table = page.getHtmlElementById("table1");
```

you can iterate over and cells with the code below

```
for (final HtmlTableRow row : table.getRows()) {
    System.out.println("Found row");
    for (final HtmlTableCell cell : row.getCells()) {
        System.out.println("   Found cell: " + cell.asText());
    }
}
```

and you can access specific cells with the example below

```
System.out.println("Cell (1,2)=" + table.getCellAt(1,2));
```

Please comment if you get stuck and I may be able to help

Comment: Thank you! But what is webClient in this case? It is implementet in this code here:  HtmlPage page = HTMLParser.parseHtml(response, webClient.getCurrentWindow());  I used: WebClient webClient = new WebClient(); but I got a exception: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.css.sac.ErrorHandler

Comment: @internet I made a project on Eclipse named Test and tried this in the main method. I have pasted all the code including the imports on pastebin. Here is the link http://pastebin.com/0QwFY5KW let me know if you still can't get it to work.

Comment: Strange, I tested your code. But the code doesn´t work :( I got a exception in here : WebClient webClient = new WebClient();    This is the full exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/css/sac/ErrorHandler
 at test.HTMLUnitTest.main(HTMLUnitTest.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.css.sac.ErrorHandler

Comment: By the way: requestSettings is never used?

Comment: @internet Are you sure you have all of HTMLUnit Jars in your project? My guess would be that you are missing some HTMLUnit Jars. As for requestSettings, you are right it is not being used in this case. Technically you can use it, but I don't see any benefit for it.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. Thank you. My main question is: I want to get the height from each row. I will create the HMTL table dynamiclly. This means each row can be another height. How can I do this?

Comment: @internet I was looking at the methods available for the HtmlTable class and I do not see a method that returns height, but there is one that returns width. You may be able to get that information by parsing the css file associated with the html file. Take a look at this link and see if any of the methods would help you http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlTable.html

Answer (score 1):

In HtmlUnit 2.51.0 up to at least 2.70.0 this worked for me:

```
  try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {

     // found here: https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/faq.html#HowToParseHtmlString
     // works for version 2.51.0 - 2.70.0 (newer not tested yet)
     HtmlPage page = webClient.loadHtmlCodeIntoCurrentWindow(pageAsString);

     // works for version 2.42.0 (not for 2.43.0)
     // HtmlPage page = new HtmlUnitNekoHtmlParser().parseHtml(response, webClient.getCurrentWindow());
  }
```

Comment: of course the first version works also with version 3.x - https://www.htmlunit.org/faq.html#HowToParseHtmlString

Comment: @RBRi; I havent switched to 3.x because of other problems yet (therefore I haven't tested it yet)